# Git - git pull dont give the expected result

Tags: git

I am working on a repo and I did some local commits and now I want to do `git pull origin develop` whithout any change .. what should I do please ?

Comment: This isn't clear - what do you mean by "without any change"?

Comment: without any change of code done in the local commits

Comment: @Lara You are trying to pull develop from the origin. In which branch you are working ?

Comment: I am on develop :)

Comment: you need only `git fetch origin develop:develop`. `git pull` will merge FETCH_HEAD to your local branch.

Comment: `git fetch origin develop:develop` did not solve my problem , I stil have changes from commits

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
git log
```

for check the commit history. There you will find your commits. Take the commit number which is before your local changes. Then do

```
git checkout -f {Commit Number}
```

Then you will be your initial state (before make any local changes). Then do

```
git pull origin develop
```

The develop branch will update then. And i think you will get your expected result.

Comment: @Lara If you face any problem on checkout then try "git checkout -f {Commit Number}" . I have updated the command. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git pull --rebase`, it will make a three way merge and make your commit be the new HEAD.
Please let me know whether this command helps.

Comment: it gives me 
`You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which
branch you want to rebase against. See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>
`
it means that I should do ` git pull origin develop` but when I do it gives me the my expected result + some changes from the local commits

Answer (score 0):

> You are not currently on a branch. Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.

That means you are currently in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309): check that with:

```
git branch -avv
```

If you think you should be in the develop branch, reset it to whare you are:

```
git checkout -B develop
```

Then you can try `git push origin develop` again.